# how did Detective Keith Frazier & Detective Bill interrogate hostages?

Tags: plot-explanation, inside-man

How did Detective Keith Frazier & Detective Bill interrogate hostages face to face in *Inside Man*, if they are under captive of Dalton?

Dalton released that heart patient guy at the start of the movie, that's all.
But in this image these two guys interrogating **old woman**, how?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the events are told in [a nonlinear way](http://www.tonymedley.com/2006/Inside_Man.htm):

> The story is told in an unusual, non linear manner, with
>   flash-forwards to interviews with people involved in the robbery a la
>   Warren Beatty’s “Reds” (1981).

[Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_narrative):

> Nonlinear narrative, disjointed narrative or disrupted narrative is a
>   narrative technique, sometimes used in literature, film, hypertext
>   websites and other narratives, where **events are portrayed, for example
>   out of chronological order,** or in other ways where the narrative does
>   not follow the direct causality pattern of the events featured, such
>   as parallel distinctive plot lines, dream immersions or narrating
>   another story inside the main plot-line. It is often used to mimic the
>   structure and recall of human memory, but has been applied for other
>   reasons as well.